# How to save a video NSData from an iOS device to php server

Tags: php, ios, nsdata

Currently I am getting a NSData for a video file from iOS device. I need to save it on the php server. I am facing a little confusion here on whether I need to create a video from that NSData or simply saving the NSData will do it. Guidance needed here on what would be the right way.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is for saving data in server from PHP or sending it to the server from device???? Please clear your question

Comment: Actually it is both ways, first I need to save data iOS device to php server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to upload that file in some location. Follow below code. The video should come with key 'media'

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['media']['tmp_name']))
                {

                    $uploaddir = realpath('./upload/video/');

                    $fname='';//give any file name to save with extension'
                    $uploadfile = $uploaddir ."/". $fname;

                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['media']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

                        $media = 'upload/video/'.$fname;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, but want to know can i get data in $_FILES variable from the iOS device ?

Comment: Its bit confusing. Please clarify your doubt.

Comment: Okay Sam, right now i am getting data in $_POST['videoNSData'], but i am very much confused if $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'] will work or not

Comment: See all the multipart data can only be accessed using $_FILES. Only form field data can be accesed using $_GET or $_POST. so if you are getting and multipart data then you have to use $_FILES. It will definitely work unless you are not getting JSON request.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam, I ll try with $_FILES. and yes i am getting all other data from iOS device in POST and not JSON

Comment: Yeah. You will get all other form data using $_POST but not video data or image data. For getting video or image data you have to use $_FILES as your are not getting JSON. If solution works don't forget to accept answer. Just mentioning because you are new comer in stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks. You learned by yourself only. Just keep it in mind for future. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This will helpful to you

```
 NSString *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mov"];
 NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: videoURL]];

 AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL      URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com"]];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"    path:@"/videoupload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id   <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
                            {
                                [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"file" fileName:@"video.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
                            }];


 AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: request];

  [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten,long long totalBytesWritten,long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
```

{

```
 NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
```

}];

```
 [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {NSLog(@"Video Uploaded Successfully");}
                              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {NSLog(@"Error : %@",  operation.responseString);}];


[operation start]
```

Comment: Susitha the code is very confusing, Please help

Comment: You can ignore the first line. You can replace the second line with your NSData object. You need to do the server side scripting for get the data at server.

Comment: Below answer that posted by @sam'solution will helpful with server side(PHP) thing.